# Portions of Custom Tabs not working

Tags: docusignapi

I am trying to create a custom tag with the REST API in WebMerge but it only semi works. DocuSign detects the `AnchorString` and `CustomTabRequired;` but the `CustomTabWidth`, `CustomTabValidationPattern` and the `CustomTabValidationMessage` does not work. As you can see I set the width to 60,000 but the text field still appears as a single character sized box. The validation pattern is suppose to detect a forward slash at the beginning and end of the recipient signature, the validation does not run at all I can leave out the forward slash and it would not run the validation message. Below is the script in JSON format -

```
{  
   "signer1":{  
      "tabs":{  
         "textTabs":[  
            {  
               "anchorString":"\\tbx_1\\",
               "anchorIgnoreIfNotPresent":"true",
               "CustomTabType":"Text",
               "CustomTabRequired":"True",
               "CustomTabWidth":"60000",
               "FontSize":"Size12",
               "CustomTabValidationPattern":"^(\\/{1})([a-zA-Z-,'.]+\\s*[a-zA-Z-,'.]*\\s*[a-zA-Z-,'.]*\\s*[a-zA-Z-,'.]+)(\\/{1})$",
               "CustomTabValidationMessage":"Incorrect signature format please use /John Doe/"
            }
         ]
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there's some errors in your tab parameters, you've got a bunch of CustomTab prefixes that shouldn't be there. Here's a sample of a tab that's more in line with what you want:

```
"textTabs": [
{
    "validationPattern": "<<regex>>",
    "validationMessage": "validation error message",
    "required": "true",
    "locked": "false",
    "tabLabel": "NameForTab",
    "fontSize": "size12",
    "width": "600",
    "height": "14",
    "tabType": "text"
}
```

Comment: Thanks Drew, this is getting me in the right direction. The field width formatting now works, but the validation is still not executing. Also where did you get the validationPattern, ValidationMessage, width and height from? They were not in the API reference documentation I have been using.

Comment: Tag parameters from the CustomTabs: Create method should apply the same to tags added to an envelope: https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/reference/CustomTabs/CustomTabs/create#CustomTabs
(Expand the CustomTabs definition reference if it isn't automatically)